# Is $X^T Y X$ Appropriately Called a Gram Matrix if $Y$ is Positive Definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, inner-products

The Gram matrix (or Gramian) of a set of vectors in an inner product space is defined as the Hermitian matrix of inner products, with entries given by $G_{ij} = \langle \mathbf{v}_i, \mathbf{v}_j \rangle$. When these vectors are the columns of a matrix $X$ and the vector coordinates are real numbers, the Gram matrix simplifies to $X^T X$, as per the traditional definition.

Recently, I've come across instances where matrices of the form $X^T Y X$ are referred to as Gram matrices, with $Y$ being a positive definite matrix. This variant seems to introduce a weighted inner product, diverging from the traditional form where $Y$ is absent.

Considering the original definition of a Gram matrix, does the inclusion of a positive definite matrix $Y$ in the form $X^T Y X$ stretch the definition too far, or is it an acceptable extension within certain contexts? I'm trying to understand whether calling $X^T Y X$ a Gram matrix is a misuse of terminology or if there's a broader interpretation that accommodates such forms.

Comment: It is a Gram matrix in the original sense. Any positive definite matrix $Y$ with real entries can be written as $S^TS$ for some matrix $S$ with real entries (in fact, one can even choose $S$ so that $S = S^T$ and even that $S$ is positive definite itself). So $X^TYX = X^TS^TSX = (SX)^T(SX)$.

Comment: For matrices with complex entries, the above also holds if you change all instances of taking transposes $^T$ to taking Hermitian conjugates $^\ast$.